# Using setInterval, But want to disable it when user input detected

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am calling a function with `setInterval` that is loading my page through an ajax get request and is outputting the response to the page sort of like a "live updates" page, I have comments being pulled and input boxes for comment submission but the problem is that when the user is inputting data into the form it's resetting meanwhile because the page is refreshing in the background with the ajax call.

My question is: How can I make it so that if there is any user input on the form (by form id maybe) to then disabled the timer, until they have left focus of the form element?

I hope this makes sense,

Comment: What do you mean 'input'? Click? Type?...

Comment: It does not restart the interval only or does not even clear the interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `clearInterval`

```
$(function() {
    var AtlassTimer,
        i = 0;

    function oncommententer()
    {
        console.log('Clear');
        clearInterval(AtlassTimer);
    }

    function oncommentleave()
    {
        console.log('Start');
        AtlassTimer  = setInterval(loadactiveusers, 1000);          
    }

    function loadactiveusers() {
        $('#result').html(i++);
    }

    $('#formId input').on({
        'keypress change': oncommententer,
        blur: oncommentleave
    });

    //Init
    oncommentleave();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: thank you so much for a working example, i will give it a go now

Comment: Can you please see my edit again, I'm doing something wrong i think.

Comment: Try triggering it when document is ready. (see edit). Also, check if you have any error in your console.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use focus and blur functions of jquery

```
var my_interval;
function start_interval(){
my_interval = setInterval(function(){
my_ajax_function()}, 2000);
}
$('input').focus( function() {
 clearInterval(my_interval);
});

$('input').blur( function() {
  start_interval();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use setTimeout instead, you can

```
var t;
t = setTimeout(function(){
    //whatever you like
}, 1000);

$('input').one('click', function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
});
```

Reading - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: He's using an interval, not a timeout.

Comment: I suggest you use [setTimeout], not [setInterval]; the reason is [setInterval] is more aggressive. [setTimeout] is run once then stop, you have to call it very time finish the current [setTimeout] task, which make you code more logical. [setInterval] would just run, till you stop it - it is like a global valuable, once you have too much, you do not even know where it come from.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `clearInterval` method as well.

```
//start the routine
var myRoutine = setInterval(blah);

//stop the routine
clearInterval(myRoutine);
```

You'll probably need to attach event listeners to your form `<input>` elements using your favorite web framework, and in those event listeners, call `clearInterval`.